# click on searchbar terminates my program on Iphones using Objective C

Tags: ios4

I want to add simple search bar in the table view.  Program getting run with no error, but when I try to add text in search bar, program gets terminates

following is my code:

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController<UISearchBarDelegate> {
    NSArray *list;

    IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;

    
    NSMutableArray *searchresult;

    BOOL isSearchon;

    BOOL canSelectRow;

    
}
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSArray *list;
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
-(void)doneSearching:(id)sender;

-(void)searchlist;



@end


//in .m


@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize list,searchBar;


-(void)doneSearching:(id)sender

{
    isSearchon=NO;

    canSelectRow=YES;

    self.tableView.scrollEnabled=YES;
    
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=nil;

    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

-(void)searchlist

{NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;

    [searchresult removeAllObjects];

    
    
    for(NSString *str in list)
    {
        NSRange titleResultsRange=[str rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];


        if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
            [searchresult addObject:str];
    }

    
}

- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar {
    
    [self searchlist];
}




- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    
if([searchText length]>0)

{isSearchon =YES;

    canSelectRow=YES;

    self.tableView.scrollEnabled=YES;

    [self searchlist];}

else{
    isSearchon =NO;


    canSelectRow=NO;

    self.tableView.scrollEnabled=NO;

    }
    
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
    
    
    
    
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    list = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"rohan",@"vidhya",@"kavita",@"pushkar",nil];

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

    searchBar.autocorrectionType=UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;

    
    
    

    searchresult=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    isSearchon =NO;

    canSelectRow=YES;

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Names";


   
}

-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar

{
    isSearchon =YES;

    canSelectRow=NO;

    self.tableView.scrollEnabled=NO;

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneSearching:)]autorelease];


}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    if(isSearchon){
        return [searchresult count];}

    else{

            return [list count];}
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if(isSearchon)
    {
        cell.text=[searchresult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];}

        else{
            cell.text=[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];}

    // Configure the cell.

    return cell;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [searchBar release];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1):

I have edited my code in my question...it works fine nw....AnyOne willing to use searchbar in tableview in Iphones can refer the code.